# How to drop rows of a particular index?

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a multiindexed dataframe. I want to drop rows with indexes which ends with `09:15:00`.

I have a reproducible code here:https://gist.github.com/RJUNS/f4ad32d9b6da8cf4bedde0046a26f368

> ```
>                                CLOSE  HIGH    LOW     OPEN    VOLUME
> 2017-09-07 09:15:00   VEDL    320.20  320.20  320.20  320.20  311
> 2017-09-07 09:30:00   ACC     1808.05 1812.95 1798.75 1806.80 21611
>                       VEDL    319.85  320.60  319.25  320.00  651516
> 2017-09-07 09:45:00   ACC     1805.00 1812.00 1802.10 1810.45 12679
>                       VEDL    319.35  320.80  318.85  319.90  417515
> 2017-09-07 10:00:00   ACC     1802.00 1807.15 1800.85 1805.00 9915
>                       VEDL    320.15  320.30  319.20  319.50  259587
> ```

in other words i want to drop row:

```
2017-09-07 09:15:00 VEDL    320.20  320.20  320.20  320.20  311
```

Note that i have multiple indexes which ends with `09:15:00`

Does anyone has any solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for select first level [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and compare with `time`:

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).time != datetime.time(9, 15)]
print (df1)

...
                    VEDL  332.20  332.75  332.00  332.55   154978
2017-09-08 08:30:00 INFY  890.00  890.00  889.70  889.70    64289
                    VEDL  331.50  332.20  331.40  332.20   393830
2017-09-08 08:45:00 INFY  889.85  890.00  889.60  890.00   142584
                    VEDL  331.70  332.00  331.20  331.40   342857
2017-09-08 09:00:00 INFY  889.65  890.10  889.25  889.85   234244
                    VEDL  331.85  332.00  331.45  331.65   458025
2017-09-08 09:30:00 INFY  886.45  889.85  885.90  889.60   365388
                    VEDL  331.45  332.40  331.20  331.70   912145
...
```

Another solution with [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_at_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_at_time.html) for positions of rows, then get `MultiIndex` values and remove by `drop`:

```
df1 = df.drop(df.index[df.index.get_level_values(0).indexer_at_time('9:15:00')])
```

Solution with comapre with string created by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).strftime('%H:%M') != '09:15']
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much, and nice meeting you again :)

Comment: awesome,  which solution is faster, first or second?

Comment: Really hard question, I try test it.